# Redirect to a particular YouTube video link if a person opens any YouTube page

Tags: networking, redirection, spoofing

I want to redirect all the users in my WiFi network who ever open YouTube or any YouTube video to a particular YouTube video.
It might require editing the URL. I don't know if we can call it URLSpoofing. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to perform DNS manipulation. In order to do that (for both http and https) you'll need to run their DNS traffic through a device that you control.

There are lots of ways to do such a thing. Your router may support web site redirects in the administration page. Another way will be to set up a DNS server on your network and configure it to bypass everything except youtube.com. You'll also need to configure your DHCP server to use your new DNS server as the default.

There's a device that will handle this for you, although it may be tricky for you to set up if you're green.

http://hakshop.myshopify.com/collections/wifi-pineapple-kits

Comment: even though i manipulate DNS, I cannot land a user in a particular video page right?

Comment: You absolutely can. Once you're in the middle of their browser and the internet, you can perform any sort of redirection or information gathering you'd like.

With the device i listed above, for instance, you could redirect any request for youtube.com to a rick-roll video, or any other URL you wish.

Comment: You'd still need to run a web server that'll do the actual URL rewrite/redirect.